# Frenet–Serret frame of Viviani's Curve

Tags: calculus

We are given Viviani's curve

\begin{align}
    x(t) &= \begin{bmatrix}
           \sin(t)\cos(t)\\ 
           \sin^2(t)\\
           \cos(t) 
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

for $0 \le t \le 2\pi$ and I need to find the Frenet-Serrret frame of it.

I calculted 
\begin{align}
    \dot{x} &= \begin{bmatrix}
           \cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t)\\ 
           2\sin(t)\cos(t)\\
           -\sin(t)
         \end{bmatrix}
  \end{align}

and 
$|\dot{x}| = \sqrt{1+sin^2(t)}$. Further I have:

\begin{align}
\\\ddot{x} & = \begin{bmatrix}-4\cos\left(t\right)\sin\left(t\right) \\2\left(\cos^2\left(t\right)-\sin^2\left(t\right)\right)\\
-cos\left(t\right)\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\\ \dot{x} \times \ddot{x} & = \begin{bmatrix}
4\cos^2\left(t\right)\sin\left(t\right) - 2\sin^3(t)\\
5\sin^2(t)\cos(t)-\cos^3(t)\\
2\cos ^4\left(t\right)+4\cos ^2\left(t\right)\sin ^2\left(t\right)+2\sin ^4\left(t\right)
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Could you please tell me if my calculations are right so far?

Comment: The third entry of $\dot{x}$ seems to have an extra $2$, which has then disappeared in the computation of $\ddot{x}$ (but where the negative sign got lost!). I'm not going to check anything else.  But in general, you really should be able to compute derivatives yourself if you're hoping to succeed in a differential geometry course.

Comment: Slightly easier to take derivatives if you realize $\sin(t)\cos(t)=\frac 12 \sin(2t)$ and $\sin^2t =\frac12(1-\cos(2t))$